# How to Properly Write SELECT Statements When Dealing with Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, select, oracle12c

To demonstrate what I am asking, I will present two tables: The Product table and the PC table. The product table contains the following information:

```
MAKER      MODEL TYPE
----- ---------- -------
A       1232     PC
A       1233     PC
A       1276     Printer
A       1298     Laptop
A       1401     Printer
A       1408     Printer
A       1752     Laptop
B       1121     PC
B       1750     Laptop
C       1321     Laptop
D       1288     Printer
D       1433     Printer
E       1260     PC
E       1434     Printer
E       2111     PC
E       2112     PC
```

The PC table contains the following information:

```
      CODE      MODEL      SPEED        RAM         HD CD              PRICE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       1232        500         64          5 12x               600
         2       1121        750        128         14 40x               850
         3       1233        500         64          5 12x               600
         4       1121        600        128         14 40x               850
         5       1121        600        128          8 40x               850
         6       1233        750        128         20 50x               950
         7       1232        500         32         10 12x               400
         8       1232        450         64          8 24x               350
         9       1232        450         32         10 24x               350
        10       1260        500         32         10 12x               350
        11       1233        900        128         40 40x               980
        12       1233        800        128         20 50x               970
```

In order to execute a query that returns all PC models, which of the following queries would be better:

```
SELECT model FROM pc;
```

OR

```
SELECT model FROM product JOIN pc USING(model);
```

Comment: *All PC models*  would be returned by `SELECT model FROM product WHERE type = 'PC'`, your queries return only those models which exist in the `pc` table, `2111` & `2112` would be missing.

Comment: SELECT Distinct model FROM product JOIN pc USING(model); is the best one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need PC models, the first query you stated will be OK to use.

In your second query, you are getting the product table content first then joining them into PC table, which is slower than your first query and since you do not need any column from Product table, it is not necessary.

You can go with the query below as an alternative, to return only PC related rows, if you do not add the where clause and there is a PC model as `1276`. your second query would return the `A - 1276 - Printer` row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT model FROM product JOIN pc USING(model) where product.type='PC';
```

Comment: Interesting, does oracle automatically ensure uniqueness? In most other SQL databases this would result in value duplication.

Comment: I think we still see duplicates in the output, but since the OP asked the second query, I thought he already run it and the duplicates does not bothered him. Adding DISTINCT after the SELECT keyword would help him in this case. Updated the answer by adding DISTINCT anyway